# Rollback Stored procedure Call is not working in the mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a student table.

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I have created a stored procedure inserting the data.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_studentinsert1`(in_id int, in_name varchar(5),inn_id int, inn_name varchar(10))
BEGIN
 DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE exit HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    begin
    
    ROLLBACK;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'SQLError occured. Triggered ROLLBACK';
    select  'err' as message;
        -- ERROR
    end;
 start transaction;
insert into  student(id,name) values(in_id,in_name);
    INSERT INTO  student(id,name)  values(inn_id,inn_name);
commit;
select * from student;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

. I have written two insert queries inside of stored procedure. I have given first two input parameters valid data, For 2nd record , I have given invalid data, once run the sp, first record inserted & 2nd record exception  happen but once exception happen , 1st record rollback not happen.

[image: sqlrollbackissueimage]

Please help me.

Comment: 1062 is "Duplicate key" - but your table does not contain any unique index. SO your handler with ROLLBACK is fired never, the error breaks the procedure, and the transaction is committed with 1st insert result stored. Add primary/unique key, cause duplicate violation - and you'll see that the whole transaction is rollbacked. https://dbfiddle.uk/hszJ5O3j

Comment: Do not try to enter the value which exeeds the column length - parameter validity is checked firstly, and 1265 is generated even when you provide duplicated value.

Comment: Hi akina, I have tried with handler type as sqlexception but rollback is not working. Please help me on this

Comment: Thanks akina I got some information from you. Is it possible any way rollback without unique key in the table?

Comment: W/o unique index there is only one option for to check the interference - CASE EXISTS with according subquery and rollback as an action.

Comment: Thanks Akina, I have got it. Please write answer in the answer section.